# SSIS Exec two packages from one parent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a parent package that needs to exec two child packages with a small delay between them.
The problem is that the 2nd package won't execute after the 10 seconds delay.
Any idea?

Thanks.

[image: SSIS]

Comment: You don't get any messages when you run it from studio in debug mode?

Comment: Just "Information" messages that have nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Does your packages work without the waiting events? Did you check the properties of the wait events? It seems they don't fire the success status so the next packages aren't reachable.

Comment: I checked now. they are both set to continue on success .

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'` in an execute SQL task worked for me.

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/5/1/creating-a-time-delay-in-ssis-when-loading-master-data-servi.html